# Problem with getting and setting in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to assign a line of text as a string, so the string can be used in a message box, although the string fails to show up in the message box when the method is executed.

```
public string version { get; set; }

public void GetVersion()
{
    var version = File.ReadAllText("version.txt");
}


private void SetBalloonTip()
{
    notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Test";
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "This is version " + version;
    notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
    this.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `var`:

```
version = File.ReadAllText("version.txt");
```

By adding the `var` (or any variable type for that matter) you're creating local variable, while you want to assign the class member.

Happens to me too sometimes, and I see this as downside of `C#` as I would expect at least a warning when compiling such a thing.

Comment: Why would you expect a warning? Declaring a local variable and assigning the return value of a function to that variable is completely legal. What, exactly, should trigger a warning?

Comment: @Cody when the local variable has the same name as "global" variable, aka class member..

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a local variable with "var version", which is separate from your property "version".  Just replace "var version" with "this.version" or just "version".

Answer (score 2):

`var version = ...` *shadows* the property with a local variable; meaning, the assignment is stored in a local variable named `version`, not the property named `version`.

`this.version = ...` will do what you want.

By the way, out of convention in C#, local variables begin with lowercase letters as you have, but properties begin with an uppercase letter -- conventions like these may help alleviate shadowing issues as you experienced here.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **var** here, you should also be aware of its purpose and implication. never use anything that you are not familiar with. This is just thumb rule.

As mentioned above, using proper casing for class member and accessing class member with **this.** are best practices.